# Error mysql instalando unicenta pos

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysqlconnector.jar

Estoy tratando de configurar **unicenta** pero me aparece el siguiente error, la base de datos esta creada en **mysql** pero es como si no tuviera acceso ayuda por favor.

[[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bueno nadie me contesto, la solución fue instalar mysql. En su versión 5.6 al parecer es con la que trabaja unicenta muchas gracias.

Comment: Funcionó como dices, instalando la versión de mysql 5.6, tenia el mismo problema, ahora funcionando.
Me podrías indicar como hacer una copia de seguridad o backup?, por si falla el programa y hubiera que volver a instalar?